# require(toFail) not working for PanGestureRecognizer and PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

Here's the problem I'm having:

I have a `PageViewController` that navigates between 4 views **horizontally** and a `PanGestureRecognizer` on a `UIView` that brings it up and down **vertically**. The issue is that the `UIView` can be panned up, but then it is stuck there. The user can only swipe horizontally with the `PageViewController`.

The goal:

Be able to pan the `UIView` up and down AND swipe left and right on the PageViewController. Basically, make the `UIView` not get stuck on screen.

This is what I have now:

I have a `PanGestureRecognizer` function in the `UIView` file that looks

```
like this:
    func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let vel = recognizer.velocity(in: self)
        print("HANDLING PAN")
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            if vel.y < 0 && !scanIsUp {
                animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .easeOut, animations: {
                    self.frame = self.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -603)
                })
                scanIsUp = true
                isScanVisible = true
            } else if vel.y > 0 && scanIsUp {
                print("vel.y hehehe")
                animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .easeOut, animations: {
                    self.frame = self.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 603)
                })
                scanIsUp = false
                isScanVisible = false
            }
            animator?.pauseAnimation()
            print("paused?")
        case .changed:
            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: backgroundImage)
            if vel.y < 0 && scanIsUp {
                animator?.fractionComplete = translation.y / -603
            } else if vel.y > 0 && !scanIsUp {
                print("vel.y hehehe pt 2")
                animator?.fractionComplete = translation.y / 603
            }
        case .ended:
            animator?.continueAnimation(withTimingParameters: nil, durationFactor: 0)
        case .possible: break
        default: break
        }
    }
```

I also have an array of `gestureRecognizers` that control the `PageViewController`. I cycle through them and require them to fail so that the user can pan the `UIView` up and down like this:

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        self.panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PFScan.handlePan))
        self.panGestureRecognizer!.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        self.panGestureRecognizer!.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.addGestureRecognizer(self.panGestureRecognizer!)
        for recognizer in self.scrollViewGestureRecognizers {
            recognizer.require(toFail: panGestureRecognizer!)
        }
    }
```

Finally, I initialize the `UIView` on the main view controller part of the PageViewController like this:

```
func setUpScanPage(scrollViewGestureRecognizers: [UIGestureRecognizer]) {

    scanPage = PFScan(scrollViewGestureRecognizers: scrollViewGestureRecognizers)

    self.view.addSubview(scanPage)
}
```

Does anyone know why the `UIView` gets stuck?? I have tried everything I know of. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Thanks a ton in advanced. Cheers,
Theo